# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 when adding CocoaAsyncSocket

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, xmpp, xmppframework

I am trying to use XMPPFramework with an iOS5 project (ARC) under xcode 4.2.1 but I am facing this problem. Once I add CocoaAsyncSocket to my project as part of preparing my project to use XMPPFramework as in [1](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/wiki/GettingStarted_iOS)I get the following error.

I have seen some other people having the "Undefined symbols for architecture armv7" but I did not find yet an answer to this particular issue I have at the moment.

I have linked to the CFNetwork and marked the GCDAsyncSocket.m as non-ARC (-fno-objc-arc) but i still get the error. Any help is appreciated.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_SSLGetBufferedReadSize", referenced from:
      ___33-[GCDAsyncSocket flushSSLBuffers]_block_invoke_0 in GCDAsyncSocket.o
      -[GCDAsyncSocket doReadData] in GCDAsyncSocket.o
  "_SSLSetIOFuncs", referenced from:
      -[GCDAsyncSocket ssl_startTLS] in GCDAsyncSocket.o
  "_SSLRead", referenced from:
      -[GCDAsyncSocket flushSSLBuffers] in GCDAsyncSocket.o
      -[GCDAsyncSocket doReadData] in GCDAsyncSocket.o
  "_SSLWrite", referenced from:
      -[GCDAsyncSocket doWriteData] in GCDAsyncSocket.o
  "_SSLClose", referenced from:
      -[GCDAsyncSocket closeWithError:] in GCDAsyncSocket.o
  "_SSLCreateContext", referenced from:
      -[GCDAsyncSocket ssl_startTLS] in GCDAsyncSocket.o
  "_SSLSetEnabledCiphers", referenced from:
      -[GCDAsyncSocket ssl_startTLS] in GCDAsyncSocket.o
  "_SSLSetCertificate", referenced from:
      -[GCDAsyncSocket ssl_startTLS] in GCDAsyncSocket.o
  "_SSLSetConnection", referenced from:
      -[GCDAsyncSocket ssl_startTLS] in GCDAsyncSocket.o
  "_SSLHandshake", referenced from:
      -[GCDAsyncSocket ssl_continueSSLHandshake] in GCDAsyncSocket.o
  "_SSLSetProtocolVersionMax", referenced from:
      -[GCDAsyncSocket ssl_startTLS] in GCDAsyncSocket.o
  "_SSLSetPeerDomainName", referenced from:
      -[GCDAsyncSocket ssl_startTLS] in GCDAsyncSocket.o
  "_SSLSetProtocolVersionMin", referenced from:
      -[GCDAsyncSocket ssl_startTLS] in GCDAsyncSocket.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You just need to add SecurityFramework in the Frameworks. I also met this same problem.

Comment: It works! I am wondering it was not indicated anywhere that the security framework is also needed. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Order is important: CFNetwork.framework first and then Security.framework ; it makes me 14 errors in compilation, after this fix, everything is OK.

Comment: Regarding my last comment, order in: Project > Build Phases > Link Library.

Comment: I am also encountering this issue. How do I can add SecurityFramework?